# Bash : conditionally moving nested duplicate directories

Tags: linux, bash

Assume I have a directory named "foo" that contains several directories:

```
foo/bar/bar/(files)
foo/bat/bat/(files)
foo/baz/qux/(files)
```

Is there a way to conditionally move the 'deepest' directory up a level so it replaces its parent directory only if its name matches its parent's name? If there is no match the goal would be to retain the current directory structure.

### Desired output:

```
foo/bar/(files)
foo/bat/(files)
foo/baz/qux/(files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -type d -regex ".*/(.*)/\1$" -exec sh -c "mv {}/* {}/../" \; -delete
```

- `-regextype posix-awk`: we need to use `posix-awk` regextype to use backward reference (`\1`)
- `-type d`: targets directories
- `-regex ".*/(.*)/\1$"`: targets files corresponding to `*/bar/bar`
- `-exec sh -c "mv {}/* {}/../"`: moves targetted directories to its parent directories
- `-delete`: deletes targetted directories

Note: you can't use `rmdir {}` within `-exec` (`find` will return a `No such file or directory` error), you need to use `-delete` option after `-exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
DIR=foo
ls $DIR | while read SUBDIR ; do
  [ -d $DIR/$SUBDIR/$SUBDIR ] || continue
  mv $DIR/$SUBDIR/$SUBDIR/* $DIR/$SUBDIR/
  rmdir $DIR/$SUBDIR/$SUBDIR
done
```